# Arabic Font iOS 11

Tags: ios, applications, font, whatsapp.app

Ever since I switched to an iOS device from Android, I have noticed that the Arabic font looks like this: [image: arabic text example]

This font is very different from the classic Arabic font and is very annoying to read. I have noticed this not only on WhatsApp but on other websites also. Is this a setting in iOS or is this a problem specific to WhatsApp? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing this:

[image]

Go to settings/general/language and double check that Arabic is higher than Urdu on the list.